# Empty file is uploading while sending the stream to remote file path using sftp in node.js

Tags: node.js, sftp, filestream

I want to send the data through streams using sftp to a remote server. while sending the file with data the receiver getting the empty file with no bytes in that file. The connections to the remote server all are is perfect.
This is my code :

```
var stream;
stream = file.createReadStream(finalsrcFilename);
console.log("stream",stream);
stream.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("data is",data.toString());
    chunk+= data.toString();
    console.log("chunk data",chunk);
}); 
stream.on('end',function(data){  
   console.log(data);
   console.log(chunk);
   sftp();
   //res.send("hello"); 
});  
stream.on('error', function(err){  
   console.log(err.stack);  
}); 
function sftp() {
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
var chunk = [];
const remotefilepath = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
sftp.connect({
    host: 'xxxxxxxx.com',
    port: '22',
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

}).then(() => {
    console.log("stream",stream);
    return sftp.put(stream,remotefilepath);
}).then((data) => {
    console.log(data, 'the data info');
    res.send(data);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'catch error');
});

}
```

If I place the chunk variable in the place of the stream like return sftp.put(chunk, filename) then I am getting the error like failed to upload the data into remote file path and the ename is too long. If I put stream then it returns the 200 status as the file is successfully uploaded to the remote file path. But at the receiver end getting an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the function sftp() initially you are declaring stream but not assigned any data, so default variable "stream" is null, and when you are uploading empty value is getting uploaded.
2. Here "chunk" is a data string, not file name. So when you try to give "chunk" instead of "stream", it throws error, because stream.put method is taking "chunk" as file name which is too long.

To handle this please refer to below article, which explains sftp to remote transfer of data in streams.

[Upload file from one API to other API in NodeJS](https://www.initpals.com/node-js/how-to-pass-upload-a-file-from-one-api-to-another-api-in-nodejs/)

Comment: I have updated the code as declaring stream as globally but still, file is uploaded as empty